# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_theme_support()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a directory and file like this:

[image]

**functions.php**

```
<?php
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
function add_theme_support() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_theme_support() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\cms\wordpress\wp-includes\theme.php:2576) in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\cms\wordpress\wp-content\themes\oxbir\functions.php on line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the function has already been defined. You need to check with if before function. Edit as below.

```
if(!function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
  function add_theme_support() {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSc6t.png

Comment: It says that 'add_theme_scripts' not found. So you need to define a function called add_theme_scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And How?  Is it correct? https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzX1C.png

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You can view more details [here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)